# Why the Webdriver command window.maximize() doesn't put the window in fullscreen?

Tags: automated-testing, nightwatchjs

I was wondering if anyone know why the WebDriver command: `.windowMaximize()` doesn't put the window of the browser (Chrome on MAC in my case) in fullscreen? The window is re-sized to fit in only half of my screen.

Is there anyway to tackle this problem? maybe by setting by myself dimensions with the command `.windowSize()` but the problem with that is that it will be only set for the screen I use at the moment and so I will have to change if I launch my script on a different screen.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Which os abd versiob if selenium?

Comment: Chrome WebDriver, sorry I forgot to mention it, I will edit the post also.

Comment: are you using a Mac?

Comment: Yes on a Mac , however my Chrome session is launched on a computer screen not on the laptop one directly.

Comment: In Selenium 3.0 & above versions maximize function sometimes doesn't work...I was resolved this -first launch the browser --->launch URL>add some implicit wait for 5 Sec. --->maximum browser.     Note: Always maximum your browser after launching the URL not before.

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac the .windowsMaximize() is interpreted as a plus button click. This represents a ***Size to best fit*** command. It is not like a Maximize on a Windows OS. It will only maximize vertically.
A workaround is to start Chrome with the start-fullscreen command:

`ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-fullscreen");`